# Rollback to Savepoint rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

New to rails here. While trying to create a record in the rails console, I'm getting this certain message:

```
(0.0ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
(0.0ms)  ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT active_record_1
=> false
```

I don't know how to debug yet and don't know where to start. Here's my model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :occurrences 
  has_many :created_submissions,
           foreign_key: "creator_id",
           class_name: "Version"
  end
```

---

```
class Occurrence < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :template, autosave: true
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :versions

end
```

I'm trying to create the record using the following method:

```
new_user = User.new
user = User.first
new_user.occurrences.build(user: user.id)
new_user.save
```

Anyone got a clue on this?

Comment: how are you starting the console?

Comment: rails c -s to start my console so that I don't make any stupid mistakes in the db

Comment: ..that's why it's rolling back then.  although you should start sandbox with `rails c --s`

Comment: if you want to learn about debugging, go ahead and read this article: http://nofail.de/2013/10/debugging-rails-applications-in-development/